# How to encode multiple records in QR code while generating QR using zxing library?

Tags: java, android, qr-code, zxing

I'm working in QR Code generator and scanner and I encode a single string record in QR Code successfully using zxing library in android but now I want to encode multiple records like name, address, email etc
How can I do that?

Here is code for encode single record in QR using zxing:

```
public Bitmap encodeQR(String value) throws WriterException {

    BitMatrix bitMatrix;
    try {
        bitMatrix = new MultiFormatWriter().encode(value, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 512, 512);
    } catch (WriterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

    return new BarcodeEncoder().createBitmap(bitMatrix);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a JSON with what ever data you need and convert it to string

and its easy to extract data from JSON when ever needed.

**For example:**

```
   {
  "question": "Do you smoke?",
  "options": [
    "Yes",
    "No"
  ]
}
```